Type guarding class in switch statement
I haven't use Typescript in many years and can't remember nor find how to type guard many classes inside a switch statement correctly.
class A {}
class B {}
class C {}

type OneOfThem = A | B | C;

function test(foo: OneOfThem): string {
    switch(/* something using foo */) {
        /* A */:
            return "A";
        /* B */:
            return "B";
        /* C */:
            return "C";

        /* should not need to use "default" as all cases are handled */
    }
}

I found and tried several options like:

Using foo.constructor
Using instanceof inside the case statements
adding an extra member to the three classes to be used in the switch statement

but none of them works (Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined').
Is my memory playing tricks and this is not possible with classes ?

You can throw an error in the default case to satisfy the exhaustive pattern matching diagnostic (example).

If I do so, I won't be warned of missing case by the type checker but will face an error at runtime, which I use typescript to avoid as much as possible


adding an extra member to the three classes to be used in the switch statement

That is indeed probably the simplest solution for your case: it uses Discriminated Union, by adding a discriminant member to each class, with literal types (i.e. not just string or number), so that you (and TypeScript) can tell apart foo is from which class:
class A {
    readonly kind = "a"
    //       ^? "a" string literal, not just `string`
}
class B {
    kind: "b" = "b"
    // ^? "b" string literal, as explicitly typed
}
class C {
    kind = "c" as const
    // ^? "c" string literal, thanks to the const assertion
}

Then simply differentiate based on this kind discriminant property:
function test(foo: OneOfThem): string { // Okay
    switch (foo.kind) {
        case "a":
            foo
            //^? A inferred by TS, based on `foo.kind === "a"` type guard
            return "A";
        case "b":
            foo
            //^? B
            return "B";
        case "c":
            foo
            //^? C
            return "C";
        /* should not need to use "default" as all cases are handled */
    }
}

Playground Link

readonly did the trick, thank you !

Indeed, to be exact you just need to make sure the discriminant property has literal type values (i.e. not just string): https://tsplay.dev/wXL79w I will make it more explicit in the answer.
